# How to seed a user at initializer with Identity asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

While working with database initializer, I can save a role and a user at my development database, but the password never works. I can not login.

This is the code, what is it lacking?

```
public class DevelopmentDbInitializer : System.Data.Entity. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            string password = "1_Changeme";
            string administrator = "Administrator";
            string adminEmail = "admin@office.com";

            // Role
            if (!context.Roles.Any(role => role.Name == Utils.Constants.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR))
            {
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                var adminRole = new IdentityRole { Name = Utils.Constants.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR };
                roleManager.Create(adminRole);
            }

            // User
            if (!context.Users.Any(user => user.UserName == administrator))
            {
                var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
                var adminUser = new ApplicationUser { Email = adminEmail, UserName = administrator, PhoneNumber = "7144251556" };
                userManager.Create(adminUser, password);
                userManager.AddToRole(adminUser.Id, Utils.Constants.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR);
            }

        }
}
```

User is at database, but there is something with the password. I also use a variant with hasher and is the same story. This code seems to work on older versions of Visual Studio an Entity.

Anything changed last year with VS and its libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Using Visual Studio 2015. I suppose it is Identity 2.0. Code came from different places at stackoverflow...